# Quadratic Residues up to given $k$

Tags: number-theory

"Given positive integer $k$, there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that all integers up to $k$, including $k$, are quadratic residues modulo $p$."

I need to prove this statement and intuitively I am almost sure that I need to use Dirichlet Theorem but I can't see how it would be useful.
How do I prove this with Dirichlet Theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the primes up to $k$ are quadratic residues $\!\pmod{p}$ then all the numbers up to $k$ are quadratic residues $\!\pmod{p}$ by the multiplicativity of Legendre symbol. So, let $2=p_1<p_2<\ldots<p_h\leq k$ the primes up to $k$. By Dirichlet's theorem there is a prime $q\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and $\equiv 1\pmod{p_n}$ for any $1\leq n\leq h$. By quadratic reciprocity
$$\left(\frac{p_n}{q}\right) = \left(\frac{q}{p_n}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{p_n}\right) = 1 $$
and we are done.

---

By combining this result with [Linnik's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnik%27s_theorem) and the PNT we get that for an infinity of primes $q$ the least quadratic non-residue $\eta_q$ fulfills $\eta_q\geq \frac{1}{6}\log q$. On the other hand, assuming the GRH we also have $\eta_q\leq 2\log^2 q$ for any prime $q$ large enough (this is Wolf's improvement on Ankeny's well-known result).